# Copy selected text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how do I copy selected text automatically by using Javascript?

For example, when I highlighted a word (by double-clicking it) in a page, and that word is being automatically copied into clipboard.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: it's duplicated, but many of the suggested answers in that question aren't relevant any more.  I think this is a good question.

Comment: Why is it do you think it is irrelevant anymore?

Comment: because half of the jquery plugins don't exist anymore.

Comment: @Neal He already did in the answer section. I'm trying to understand the jQuery plugin and how to manipulate this thing.

Comment: @AimanB I meant to make a new answer in the question that you are duplicating.

Comment: @Neal Oh okay. I don't think there is a way to do what I wanted here. I still have to create a button to copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to use: https://code.google.com/p/liveclipboard-jquery

some versions of ie can do this natively.

Comment: Alright thanks mate, I'll have a look on this one.